# What is to be used to switch the load: Relay or MOSFET?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, circuit-design, switching

I have a circuit that requires to switch on/off the load using arduino control signal. The load uses 5V DC and upto 3A current. MOSFET or relay must be used to switch the load supply on/off. Input to my circuit is continuous 5V DC.

**Which should I use either a relay or MOSFET?**

I have used IRF540 MOSFET which works but after it switches on the load voltage is only 3V, which is very less power to the load.

**If I have to use a MOSFET what type of MOSFET is preferrable?**

Comment: You're not providing enough voltage to the gate of the IRF540. That FET should be suitable for this situation, just drive it with an appropriate voltage.

Comment: It is OK to try out ***IRL540N***, which is logical level trigger (5V, TTL), but not the very old ***IRF540N***, which is 7+V trigger (Vgs(th) > 7V).

Comment: The IRL540N is still an n-FET. Won’t work.

Comment: You can use any n-Mosfet in its stead which has a low enough turn-on gate threshold voltage and sufficient drain current rating. The Mosfet must be between the load and ground, keep 5V permanently on the high side of the load.

Comment: @hacktastical Of course an n Mosfet will work..I think you misunderstood a part of the question. This is a completely standard low side switch n-Fet application. Yes one could build a p-Fet high side switch instead but that would be more awkward and unusual.

Comment: For switching loads (e.g. dimming an RGB LED stripe via PWM) using an Arduino (including 3.3V ESP boards), I primarily use the IRLZ44N MOSFET. It switches enough load at 2V gate-to-source voltage. Most MOSFET datasheets feature a graph showing the transfer characteristics (gate-to-source voltage -> drain current), that graph is what you are looking for to determine the MOSFET type you need. Also, the L in the type number seems to suggest "low gate voltage" in my experience, so you might want to take a closer look at MOSFETs featuring an L.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a MOSFET, my preference, you need to chose one suitable for the application. This includes current, voltage, load, etc. With the Arduino you need a Logic Level preferably a UIS rated mosfet. The MOSFET must be properly enhanced (see graph on data sheet) to determine the Vgs voltage required to do this. Keep your load and allowable voltage drop in mind. Be sure the grounds are connected. When it is on measure the voltage between the source and drain, it should be less than 0.2 volts, if more you are not properly driving it.  The IRF540  is not designed for logic level inputs. Its threshold can be as high as 4 volts. With the Arduino it is wise to put a pull down or pull up resistor to guarantee the output state while it is in reset and your code takes over. This will prevent output glitches.

Answer (score 3):

The IRF540 is an n-channel device. This requires the gate to be brought *higher* than the source to turn on. What’s happening instead is that the FET is following the gate voltage, *minus the threshold voltage*. So if the n-FET gate is at 5V, and threshold is 2V, then it won’t conduct if the drain is higher than (5V-2V), or 3V. So it swings to that and pinches off.

Instead, use a p-FET, which switches on when the gate is *lower* than the source. Gate at GND, FET is fully on, gate at 5V, FET is fully off. The AO3401A is a 4A device that would work fine for this, but any ‘logic level’ p-FET rated for the current you need would work.

If you decide you need a relay (maybe you want dry contacts?) consider that you’ll still probably need a FET to drive its coil. This is more easily done if you drive the low side with an n-FET, but a p-FET on the high side works too. Either way, don’t forget the catch diode: without it, the coil flyback will kill your FET.

Comment: But what if the logic pin can't even reach 5V. Then the pFet will be never fully depleted (still off though). It's more usual to put an n-Fet between ground and load. But use one with low enough threshold

Comment: The threshold voltage for the FET will give some margin on the high side. The AO3401A has a low threshold of only -0.9V typical. If that is an issue, a pull-up to 5V will overcome that.

Comment: How will a pull-up solve this ? That would only work if the logic pin is an open-drain output. If it is e.g. a 3.3V push-pull output, you can't drive it higher than 3.3V with a pull-up and the pFet will be always on.

Comment: A p-FET with a less aggressive (higher) threshold (e.g, -2.5V) would also work.

Comment: If the output is push-pull CMOS it will swing to the 5V rail if there’s no other loading on the pin sinking current. If it’s TTL it won’t, but it can nevertheless be pulled up to 5V as if it were open-collector.

Comment: If you connect 5V to a 3.3 V push-pull output then the output will still stay a diode drop above VDD. A pull-up won't change this . It will just change the current that the output is sinking into its VDD supply. Also this situation is quite unusual.

Comment: @hacktastical i will try with AO3401A mosfet , from the arduino ic i get 5V from the logic pin , so when i give 5V to the gate of this Mosfet and i connect my load to ground through the drain and source.  Then at 5V from arduino pin the load will not be powered on and if the arduino pin gives 0V then the load will be powered on . Is that what you say

Comment: @GOPIR yes that is how it will work, if the Arduino is a 5V device. If you use one with 3.3 V pushpull outputs, then there can be problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a MOSFET if you want something small and cheap, and you do not require the control circuit to be isolated from the circuit you are switching. Also if you want fast, bounce-free switching.

If you require the circuits to be physically isolated from each other, and contact bounce and slow switching are not a issue, relays are hard to beat. For instance, in large installations, where separate systems that don't have a common signal ground need a simple way to exchange control information, "closed loop" signalling with relays can be a good option. (Opto couplers might be another.)